# Reading Changing and printing a PPM image

Tags: c, arrays, function, parsing, ppm

I have found code on stack overflow to do this but I'm having some errors using it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because I don't have much experience with ppm files. Thank you all for any help.

```
    typedef struct {
     int x, y;
     PPMPixel *data;
} PPMImage;

#define CREATOR "RPFELGUEIRAS"
#define RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR 255

static PPMImage *readPPM(const char *filename = "ukraine.ppm")
{
         char buff[16];
         PPMImage *img;
         FILE *fp;
         int c, rgb_comp_color;
         //open PPM file for reading
         fp = fopen("ukraine.ppm", "rb");
         if (!fp) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
              exit(1);
         }

         //read image format
         if (!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)) {
              perror(ukraine.ppm);
              exit(1);
         }

    //check the image format
    if (buff[0] != 'P' || buff[1] != '6') {
         fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image format (must be 'P6')\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    //alloc memory form image
    img = (PPMImage *)malloc(sizeof(PPMImage));
    if (!img) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    //check for comments
    c = getc(fp);
    while (c == '#') {
    while (getc(fp) != '\n') ;
         c = getc(fp);
    }

    ungetc(c, fp);
    //read image size information
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &img->x, &img->y) != 2) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image size (error loading '%s')\n",       ukraine.ppm);
         exit(1);
    }

    //read rgb component
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &rgb_comp_color) != 1) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Invalid rgb component (error loading '%s')\n",      filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    //check rgb component depth
    if (rgb_comp_color!= RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR) {
         fprintf(stderr, "'%s' does not have 8-bits components\n",       filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    while (fgetc(fp) != '\n') ;
    //memory allocation for pixel data
    img->data = (PPMPixel*)malloc(img->x * img->y * sizeof(PPMPixel));

    if (!img) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    //read pixel data from file
    if (fread(img->data, 3 * img->x, img->y, fp) != img->y) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error loading image '%s'\n", filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return img;
}
void writePPM(const char *filename = "ukraine.ppm", PPMImage *img)
{
    FILE *fp;
    //open file for output
    fp = fopen(ukraine.ppm, "wb");
    if (!fp) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n",filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    //write the header file
    //image format
    fprintf(fp, "P6\n");

    //comments
    fprintf(fp, "# Created by %s\n",CREATOR);

    //image size
    fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n",img->x,img->y);

    // rgb component depth
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n",RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR);

    // pixel data
    fwrite(img->data, 3 * img->x, img->y, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void changeColorPPM(PPMImage *img)
{
    int i;
    if(img){

         for(i=0;i<img->x*img->y;i++){
              img->data[i].red=RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR-img->data[i].red;
              img->data[i].green=RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR-img->data[i].green;
              img->data[i].blue=RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR-img->data[i].blue;
         }
    }
}

int main(){
    PPMImage *image;
    image = readPPM("can_bottom.ppm");
    changeColorPPM(image);
    writePPM("can_bottom2.ppm",image);
    printf("Press any key...");
    getchar();

    return(0);
}
```

Error message

```
[21:47:34] cehutto@hornet6:~/101/lab12 [8] gcc imageChange.c imageChange.c:18:47: error: expected â;â, â,â or â)â before â=â token
imageChange.c:94:36: error: expected â;â, â,â or â)â before â=â token
imageChange.c: In function âmainâ: imageChange.c:137:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] 
[21:47:34] cehutto@hornet6:~/101/lab12 [9] Last login: Tue Apr 14 21:28:19 2015 from 48.253.21.198.tigernet.wifi.dyn.clemson.edu
[23:42:52] cehutto@hornet6:~ [1]`
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around several strings.  Seems like if you're going to pass a filename parameter you should actually use it.  You also can't have a default parameter followed by a non-default parameter.  None of these issues are PPM issue, they're just incorrect C.

Comment: to avoid confusion, please indent (say 4) spaces after every opening brace '{" and un-indent before every closing brace '}'   use this consistent indentation even if the braces are not include after a 'if', 'do', 'while', 'else' statement

Comment: which is line 18?  which is line 137?

Comment: in general, do not 'typedef' a struct definition.  it just clutters the code, leads to mis-understanding by us humans, and clutters the compiler name space.

Comment: there are no 'default' parameter values in C.  so the code does not compile.  the #include for stdio.h is missing to functions like printf, fgets, getchar, etc are using defaults (I.E. return value and all parameters are considered to be int's

Comment: the type PPMPixel is not defined in the posted code

Comment: rather than using fprintf(stderr, .. ) to report a system error, use perror() as that will also output the appropriate error message related to the current value of the 'errno' system variable.

Comment: Can anyone point out what I can change to fix it? And the PPMPixel is in a header file.

Answer (score -1):

the following code cleanly compiles.

it is hardcoded for file ukraine.ppm

You can easily modify the file to use a file global char array

that main sets for the input file

You can easily modify the file to use a file global char array

that main sets for the output file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct PPMPixel
{
    char red;
    char blue;
    char green;
};

struct PPMImage
{
     unsigned x, y;
     struct PPMPixel *data;
};

#define CREATOR "RPFELGUEIRAS"
#define RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR (255)

static struct PPMImage *readPPM()
{
     char buff[16];
     struct PPMImage *img;

     FILE *fp;

     int c;
     int rgb_comp_color;

     //open PPM file for reading
     fp = fopen("ukraine.ppm", "rb");
     if (!fp)
     {
         perror( "fopen for ukraine.ppm failed" );
         // fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
          exit(1);
     }

     // implied els,e fopen successful

     //read image format // get first 15 bytes of image file
     if (!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp))
     {
          perror("ukraine.ppm");
          exit(1);
     }

     // implied else, fgets successful

    //check the image format
    if (buff[0] != 'P' || buff[1] != '6') {
         fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image format (must be 'P6')\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, image file file has correct format indicators

    //alloc memory for image
    img = malloc(sizeof(struct PPMImage));
    if (!img)
    {
        perror( "malloc for PPMImage failed" );
        //fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    //check for comments
    c = getc(fp);
    while (c == '#')
    {
        while( (c = getc(fp)) != '\n') ;
    }

    //read image size information
    if (fscanf(fp, "%u %u", &img->x, &img->y) != 2)
    {
        perror( "fscanf for ukraine.ppm image size parameters failed" );
         exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, fscanf successful

    //read rgb component
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &rgb_comp_color) != 1)
    {
        perror( "fscanf for rgb_comp_color in ukraine.ppm failed" );
         //fprintf(stderr, "Invalid rgb component (error loading '%s')\n",      filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, fscanf successful

    //check rgb component depth
    if (rgb_comp_color!= RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "'ukraine.ppm' does not have 8-bits components\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, rgb component depth correct

    // consume rest of line
    while (fgetc(fp) != '\n') ;

    //memory allocation for pixel data
    img->data = malloc(img->x * img->y * sizeof( struct PPMPixel));

    if ( !img->data ) //< corrected element being checked
    {
        perror( "malloc for pixel data failed" );
        //fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    //read pixel data from file
    if (fread(img->data, 3 * img->x, img->y, fp) != img->y)
    {
        perror( "fread for pixel data failed" );
        // fprintf(stderr, "Error loading image '%s'\n", filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, fread successful

    fclose(fp);
    return img;
} // end function: readPPM


void writePPM(struct PPMImage *img)
{
    FILE *fp;
    //open file for output
    fp = fopen("ukraine.ppm", "wb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror( "fopen for ukraine.ppm for write failed" );
        // fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n",filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    //write the header file
    //image format
    fprintf(fp, "P6\n");

    //comments
    fprintf(fp, "# Created by %s\n",CREATOR);

    //image size
    fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n",img->x,img->y);

    // rgb component depth
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n",RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR);

    // pixel data
    fwrite(img->data, 3 * img->x, img->y, fp);
    fclose(fp);
} // end function: writePPM


void changeColorPPM(struct PPMImage *img)
{
    unsigned i;
    if(img)
    {

         for(i=0;i<img->x*img->y;i++)
         {
              img->data[i].red=RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR-img->data[i].red;
              img->data[i].green=RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR-img->data[i].green;
              img->data[i].blue=RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR-img->data[i].blue;
         }
    }
} // end function: changeColorPPM


int main()
{
    struct PPMImage *image;
    image = readPPM();
    changeColorPPM(image);
    writePPM(image);
    printf("Press any key...");
    getchar();

    return(0);
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Thank you when I compile it it says this fread for pixel data failed: Success I'm assuming that means it worked. I'm not seeing where it creates the manipulated image? @user3629249